# Flutter different theme for Android and iOs

Tags: dart, flutter

I want to use a different theme for my flutter app, depending on the OS it's started on. How can i detect the OS when choosing what theme to apply?

```
Theme.of(context).platform == TargetPlatform.iOS
```

doesn't work, because I haven't applied a theme yet...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can easily override theme by wrapping your view into a new `Theme` instance with custom properties.

You could do the following :

```
return new MaterialApp(
  // default theme here
  theme: new ThemeData(),
  builder: (context, child) {
    final defaultTheme = Theme.of(context);
    if (defaultTheme.platform == TargetPlatform.iOS) {
      return new Theme(
        data: defaultTheme.copyWith(
          primaryColor: Colors.purple
        ),
        child: child,
      );
    }
    return child;
  }
);
```

Which would specify a default theme. And then override `primaryColor` for IOS.

Comment: When using this method I cannot overwrite certain values, for example fontFamily and a few other things... Is there any other way maybe?

Comment: Use `new ThemeData()` instead of `defaultTheme.copyWith` then. But you'll have to manually assign old values